# How to prevent MUI Grid alignment from changing on smaller screens?

Tags: css, flexbox, material-ui, grid

I have an MUI Grid setup and am facing problems with its alignment properties. Given below is the desired UI. The same design is achieved on larger screens but when opened on smaller devices it kind of changes the MUI Grid row into a column.

##### The expected output

[image]

##### Actual Output

[image]

##### Code Snippet

```
<Grid
      container
      justifyContent={"space-between"}
      alignItems={"center"}
      sx={{
        backgroundColor: "#f9fcff",
        borderBottom: "1px solid rgba(2, 59, 100, 0.05);",
      }}
    >
      <Grid item p={1} flex={0.9}>
        <Grid container alignItems={"center"} columnSpacing={3}>
          <Grid item>
            <Avatar
              src={""}
              sx={{
                width: 60,
                height: 60,
              }}
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            <Grid container columnGap={1}>
              <Grid item>
                <Typography
                  variant="recipientName"
                  noWrap
                  sx={{ wrap: "break-word" }}
                >
                  {`${item.firstName} ${item.lastName}`}
                </Typography>
              </Grid>

              <Grid
                item
                sx={{
                  width: "112px",
                  height: "40px",
                  borderRadius: "5px",
                  backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 109, 63, 0.1)",
                  display: "flex",
                  justifyContent: "center",
                  alignItems: "center",
                }}
              >
                <Typography variant="recipientClassName">
                  {item.class.title}
                </Typography>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
        <Checkbox
          icon={<RadioButtonUncheckedIcon />}
          checkedIcon={<CheckCircleIcon />}
        />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

What I need is that it should get wrapped and not change the direction of the Grid. On smaller screens, the name text field having a blue border and class name tag should always stay on the same row and not come one above the other as it happens in the second name.

Any solutions by using which this transformation of Grid row into column can be prevented?

Thanks in advance.